# Why does my Cassandra Lucene Index not return all results?

Tags: lucene, cassandra

We have 2 queries which should return the same result.  But the 2nd query  returns a lot less results or sometimes no results. These are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3';
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3' AND text = '{ sort: {fields: [{field: "speed", reverse: true}]}}';.
```

We use this custom cassandra index https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index.

Otherwise do you have better alternatives?

Thank you the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Otherwise do you have better alternatives?

There is an integration of **Cassandra** with **Apache Solr** called **[DSE Search](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html)**. But obviously it's not free

Other than the Stratio Lucene index implementation, the only other existing open-source Lucene index impl I know is **[Stargate Core](http://tuplejump.github.io/stargate/)**. I'm not sure if it's mature or production-ready, their github seems quite idle (last commit = October 2015)

Answer (score 3):

It has been solved at https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/259.

In short, the `SELECT COUNT` clause was using internal paging, that is [not supported before 3.6.0 release](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.9/CHANGELOG.md#360-june-18-2016).

The solution is either disable paging or update to a newer release.