# What are good alternatives to the Cassandra Lucene Index?

Tags: lucene, cassandra

Since I constantly have this problem described below I would like to change but lack of a better alternative.

I have 2 queries which should return the same result. But the 2nd query returns a lot less results or sometimes no results. These are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3';
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3' AND text = '{ sort: {fields: [{field: "speed", reverse: true}]}}';.
```

I use this custom cassandra index https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index.

EDIT:

I use Cassandra 2.2.4.1 cassandra-lucene-index 2.2.4

'text' is the table column over which I have built the index.

My Index creation query is:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statistics_text_idx ON toutiao.statistics (text) USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index' WITH OPTIONS = {'schema': '{
            fields : {
                title: {
                                    type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
                                    category : {type:"string"},
                    genre : {type:"string"},
                    speed  : {type : "integer",sorted : true}
            }
    }', '
            refresh_seconds': '1'};
```

Table creation query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statistics;

CREATE TABLE statistics (
source text,
timespan text,
id text,
title text,
thumbnail text,
url text,
text text,
created_at timestamp,
category text,
category2 text,
genre text,
author text,
reads int,
likes int,
comments int,
shares int,
speed int,
PRIMARY KEY (source, timespan, id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timespan DESC) AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}';
```

This is my data insert program:

```
cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])
session_statis = cluster.connect(keyspace)
session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO tablename(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11,value12,value13,value14,value15))
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Question answered here (for alternative to Stratio index): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938494/why-does-my-cassandra-lucene-index-not-return-all-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doanduyhai already answered this in your other thread but I thought I'd chime in here as well.

When it comes to 'search' for Cassandra data, you have a few options and it depends on a few things such as SLA's, ease of use, free VS. paid, etc. Stratio is definitely an interesting open source option - not sure where your problems stem from but I haven't seen it in production (I'm sure people are using it, just haven't seen it)

As for alternatives, you essentially have two options:

```
Option 1 - roll your own established Lucene based search API.
```

Your choices here are ElasticSearch or Solr. Both offer their own advantages and have open source options. The challenge here is that you will have to manage a separate cluster and either ETL data from Cassandra or dual write. In this scenario, you have a little more flexibility since this can act as a generic search cluster if you have many systems. This does mean you have manage failure scenarios yourself (such as split brain problems) and you lose Lucene integration in CQL.

```
Option 2 - Go the enterprise route (disclaimer: I work for DataStax)
```

DataStax Enterprise has an integrated search option that's quite good. Solr shares the same JVM as Cassandra which allows for Cassandra data to be immediately be indexed and take advantage of Cassandra availability. There's also some cool query routing that happens to make search more efficient. See: [DSE Search](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html). This is obviously a paid option - though free to use in development.

Answer (score 4):

I think i know what you are doing bad,

Is 'text' the table column over which you have builded the index???

Can you post here your cassandra version, cassandra-lucene-index version and your index creation query?

(disclaimer: I work in Stratio :))

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I added the information you requested in the EDIT section in the post above. Would be great if you could help out!

Comment: Sorry, but i need more info to be able to reproduce this. Can you please open an issue in [github](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues) with table creation query and some inserts???

Comment: I added the creation query table above. Looking forward to your feedback. Thanks

Comment: I also added the data insertion program. Looking forward to your reply! thanks

Comment: Hi, what i mean with inserts is real DATA to try to reproduce this issue. Please, can you open an issue [here](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues) ???

Comment: It seems to me, the cassandra-lucence project is dead (archived on github).
is there any follow up i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

For fast testing of your query, add Kibana, part of the ELK stack that would generate the function you're trying to accomplish, and generate the elasticsearch/Lucene code that meets your requirements. Your es will need to match whatever Kibana release you pull down: for the latest release of Kibana in Dec 2015, I had to go from es 2 to 2.1 to match current Kibana. Since es is now at some flavor of 2.2, Kibana may have upgraded as well. ah...just checked for you...Kibana at 4.4 requires es 2.2 ... so the rollouts are happening fast.

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana

disclosure: my primary is gptext, madlib and plr,  but i love es.....:) gptext would be more SQL-like ... similar to what you have above...